# Last day of century BQ

Tags: date, google-bigquery

How can we get the last day of the century in Bigquery?
Is there a formula I can use to set the value of a column like this:'2099-12-31' ?

so far I have used the direct assignment of the value DATE('2099-12-31') but I would like to use a formula that would lead to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Below super simple example should give you an idea

```
with data as (
  select 21 as century union all
  select 20 
)
select century, date(century * 100, 1, 1) - 1 as last_day_of_century
from data
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this instead of simply using `DATE('2099-12-31')` but you could do some maths on current_date:

```
SELECT DATE((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) DIV 100 ) * 100 + 99, 12, 31) as end_of_century
```

- extract year = 2023
- 2023 DIV 100 = 20
- 20 * 100 = 2000
- 2000 + 99 = 2099

This should also work for the next century but I won't guarantee the ability to verify this personally.

With now as late 2023, it will be 76 (+ a bit) before the string 2099-12-31 needs updating.